# Arduino COM port not found

Tags: serial-port, usb, arduino

For the past week I have been programming an Arduino Uno with a computer running Windows 7. When I first started, I found the device on COM6 and was able to upload code no problem. Recently it suddenly stopped receiving code under the error:

> Serial port 'COM6' not found. Did you select the right one from the
>   Tools > Serial Port menu?

The *Serial port* menu though is grayed out. Research has told me to open up Device Manager and update drivers but there is no other devices tab in my Device Manager. The Arduino is run off the power of the USB cable and runs the code I uploaded a few days ago just fine. What can I do to be able to upload code to the Arduino?

**Update:**

I installed the Arduino software on another computer and it does not recognize the Arduino either. One of the comments indicates that this could be a problem with the FTDI chip. How can I test if this is the case, and if it is, can I fix it?

Comment: I hope this isn't to cliche' of an answer however. Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: Yes, at this point I have unplugged it and plugged it back in and restarted everything several times.

Comment: try going into device manager and verifying what com port your arduino is sitting on. It could be that you have a bad cable. They go bad more often than one would think

Comment: I hate when people downvote perfectly reasonable questions/answers without comment... here's an upvote

Comment: @Pyrce: Yeah, that's what I thought, too...

Comment: It can be a broken cable, too. I had this issue that the official Arduino cable did not work, but my Samsung mobile loading cable worked properly...

Answer (score 1):

For Linux:

To solve the problem, simply run the IDE as super user, so go to terminal and type 'sudo arduino'.

To solve this problem permanently:

In the terminal, run 'gksudo gedit'

In gedit, open the */usr/share/applications/arduino.desktop* file.

Change the line `Exec=arduino` 
to `Exec=gksudo arduino`. Save the file.
Similarly, do the same for Windows...

Also try to re-install Arduino driver.

Comment: This is seriously bad advice. DO NOT RUN ANY GUI SOFTWARE SUDO! Do the right thing and adjust the usb serial port access rights.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of cable:

1. Charging Cable
2. Data Transfer Cable

So try changing the cable, if you have already tried every USB driver and port; or else

Install a new driver using this link, http://www.wch.cn/download/CH341SER_MAC_ZIP.html.
But after installing the driver, if it doesn't work, then change the cable.

Comment: How would it be able to be COM6 initially with a charging cable (from the question: *"When I first started, I found the device on COM6"*)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen most of the time charging cable doesn't work, you need data transfer cable in order to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino probably started using a different port. When you plug Arduinos into a different USB port it sometimes defaults to a new COM port. Check your device settings for which ports are being used and try each of those. Also try plugging it into a different USB port (if no ports are displayed) and it should register with a new COM. If that fails reboot your machine and repeat the above. If that fails reinstall the Arduino USB driver and repeat above. If that fails you might have fried your Arduino's USB chip (or some other hardware on the Arduino).

Comment: I have tried all of the ports and verified with my mouse they all work, how do I view my "device settings"?

Comment: Go to your control panel and select/search for "Device Manager" it should give you a list of hardware components and one of those is the Serial port which you can expand to see active ports

Comment: The device manager does not have a serial ports in its list, it does have usb controllers but that just expands into a list of the port names

Comment: It should be under "Ports (COM & LTP)". If you can't see that you might need to re-install the Arduino usb driver. There's also a distinct possibility that your FTDI chip in the USB cable/on the Arduino is dead.

Comment: I re installed the drivers but it did not help, should I test if its the FTDI chip by downloading the software on another computer and trying to connect?

Comment: I would try it on another machine or try connecting to a different Arduino with the same cable (depending on what you have available).

Answer (score 0):

For Linux: Vinayk93 is completely right. Adjust the serial port's access rights like so:

$ cd /dev/ ; ls -l ttyA*  -- find the right portname, then

$ sudo chmod 666 ttyACMx  -- x is 0 or 1